# Android Inner Join Select Statement

Tags: android, sql

I’ve just attempted my first Inner Join, Select statement in Android and it doesn’t work. The database it’s self has no relationships set up as I don’t know how to do that yet if possible at all. I am able to select from both tables individually, but the following select doesn’t work.

```
return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, FacilityName FROM Facility INNER JOIN BeachFacility ON Facility.FacilityID = BeachFacility.FacilityFK WHERE BeachFK=?", args));
```

Is there something I’m missing or more I need to know to do this?

Cheers,

Mike.

---

If anyone is interested.

The database model I came up with for this exercise was to leave all the primary key names at _id and the middle table i.e.. beaches_facilities table that sits between beaches and facilities, I renamed the primary key field in there to BF_id.

This way I can still reference the main tables with the _id key in other queries and it works beautifully.

Thanks all!

Comment: Does it give you errors or no results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are following Android's _id convention, the assumption would be that both of your tables have that column.

With that being said, the query above would probably throw a "Ambiguous column _id" error.   Qualify your tables as Yaqub mentioned and you should be ok.

Also, always test out your queries in the sqlite client first.  Save yourself the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

How to create relation between two tables, see [this](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html).
I don't see anything wrong with your query, below is a sample of joining two tables:

```
private final String mySQL = "SELECT * FROM firstTable a INNER JOIN secondTable b ON a.id = b.id WHERE b.Field=?";
```